# m2e will not install on Eclipse 3.5.2

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

I have Eclipse 3.5.2 setup on a linux vm. The install is fresh, I have not added any other plugins to Eclipse. When I attempt to install any version of M2E using Eclipse's install feature from Indigo repository - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo I will get the following error

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>     Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.0.200.20111228-1245 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.0.200.20111228-1245)
>     Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 3.5.2 (Eclipse Platform 3.5.2)
>     Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>       Common Navigator View 3.5.101.v20120106-1355 (org.eclipse.ui.navigator 3.5.101.v20120106-1355)
>       Common Navigator View 3.5.100.v20110809-2227 (org.eclipse.ui.navigator 3.5.100.v20110809-2227)
>       Common Navigator View 3.4.1.M20090911-1550 (org.eclipse.ui.navigator 3.4.1.M20090911-1550)
>       Common Navigator View 3.5.100.I20110524-0800 (org.eclipse.ui.navigator 3.5.100.I20110524-0800)
>       Common Navigator View 3.4.2.M20100120-0800 (org.eclipse.ui.navigator 3.4.2.M20100120-0800)
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse Platform 3.5.2 (Eclipse Platform 3.5.2)
>       To: org.eclipse.ui.navigator [3.4.2.M20100120-0800]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.0.200.20111228-1245 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.0.200.20111228-1245)
>       To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.0
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.v20110530-9gF7UHNFFt4cwE-pkZDJ7oz-mj4OSEIlu9SEv0f (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.0.v20110530-9gF7UHNFFt4cwE-pkZDJ7oz-mj4OSEIlu9SEv0f)
>       To: org.eclipse.ui.navigator [3.5.100.I20110524-0800]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9gF7UHOxFtniV7mI3T556iZN9AU8bEZ1lHMcVK (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9gF7UHOxFtniV7mI3T556iZN9AU8bEZ1lHMcVK)
>       To: org.eclipse.ui.navigator [3.5.100.v20110809-2227]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q)
>       To: org.eclipse.ui.navigator [3.5.101.v20120106-1355]

Is M2E not supported in this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The M2E download page states that "m2e is tested against Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) and 4.3 (Kepler) Milestone builds", so possibly not.  Why use such an old build in the first place?

Comment: There certainly were m2e builds for Indigo — I have one on this machine — but a different update site might be needed for them.

Comment: performing the same steps on a newer version worked without any issue so I a inclined to believe it is not compatible, at the least not compatible without some tinkering.

Comment: love it, just love it when people say use newer version of eclipse. Convince oracle to release a new version of OEP eclipse plugins that work with weblogic portal (they wont) or convince my company to stop using weblogic portal (would cost a few million dollars). Otherwise reality is some people are stuck on older technologies =(. Is there any way to get it to work on eclipes 3.5?